# hide and how to show bootstrap alert message using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i used bootstrap alert message in my login page 
but when i click the button, the message does not appear, just the alert div was shown.. can anybody help me
thank in advance

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", "
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert-danger').show();
    $('.alert-danger').html('Invalid User name');
  });
</script>");
```

Comment: What is the "Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock" part about? Doesn't look like JS.

Comment: You might want to use your browser's built-in console and run the commands by hand to see if the JS code is okay.

Comment: yah, i know is not js, it is a method related to .net environment, but my problem with the java script part which is the parameter here..

Comment: it says "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3"

Comment: I change my version of jQuery, but still does not work

Comment: "does not work" is not a helpful error description. Please try using the developer tools in your browser first. Get your JS to work this way before including it in your .NET app.

Comment: "Get your JS to work this way before including it in your .NET app." I dont understand what do you mean by this, could you please clarify that

Comment: where should i attach js files? in the header tag or at the end of html page?

Comment: None of those. In your browser there is a developer tools bar (F12). one of the tools is called console. you can use it to run any JavaScript and see the effect live. If you can't find the console, use a script element inside your HTML. point is: get your JS right first, only then include it server-side.

Comment: Wait, are you sure you have Bootstrap and jQuery included in the page?

Comment: I include it in the head tag of master page, and then apply the master to the login page "meaning content page does not containing any attachment ", is it correct?

Comment: YOU are Greeeeeeate .. Thank you .....

Comment: I'm new in stack, How can i vote for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try change the order of elements, like:

```
$('.alert-danger').html('Invalid User name');  
$('.alert-danger').show();
```

Everything looks fine, idk why the message is not showing up